How do I solve this issue - Error opening emulator?
Recently, when I try to run my emulator on Android Studio, I get this error message:
INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db, detection is enabled for process: 17440 INFO | Android emulator version 34.2.15.0 (build_id 11906825) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\hp\.jdks\openjdk-21.0.1\system-images\android-28\google_apis\x86\ INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: f8ed:ca89:c002:0:70cd:ca89:c002:0 (2x) ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.15.db, detection is enabled for process: 4496 INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. INFO | Increasing RAM size to 3072MB INFO | IPv4 server found: 41.75.80.84 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 70cd:ca89:c002:0:70cd:ca89:c002:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 70cd:ca89:c002:0:70cd:ca89:c002:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 88d3:ca89:c002:0:70cd:ca89:c002:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 88d3:ca89:c002:0:70cd:ca89:c002:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: f0e1:ca89:c002:0:70cd:ca89:c002:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: f0e1:ca89:c002:0:70cd:ca89:c002:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 10e8:ca89:c002:0:70cd:ca89:c002:0 INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 10e8:ca89:c002:0:70cd:ca89:c002:0 (2x) INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: f8ed:ca89:c002:0:70cd:ca89:c002:0
I have tried to install Haxm and I'm still getting errors although everything used to work well before.

Try to wipe the emulator data and try to open it again.
